# Unsupported Project Visual studio13

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssas, cube

I am trying to open a Visual studio project using VS13, but I get an unsupported message. This includes a cube project (.dwproj) and an sql project (.sqlproj). The project have been created with VS13 and I got it through tortoise SVN. I have already installed only MS SQL Server Data Tools (from VS13 with update4). Any thoughts?

> Unsupported
>   This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
>   For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
>        - Cubes, 
>   "C:\Cubes.dwproj"

Comment: Have you got something like this installed to add support for the dwproj? https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=42313

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded 'SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2013' and it worked, despite that I had already installed data tools from VS 2013 Ultimate & from SQL Server 2012.